# Curly arrow from a matrix to another

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices, tikz-arrows

I am trying to put an arrow that goes from a matrix to another one with some text above.
I came with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tikz[remember picture] \node (n3){1};  & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tikz[remember picture] \node (n4){1}; & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick]  (n3) to [out=45,in=135] node[above] {some text here} (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but the two number higlighted by `\node` command are "floating" with respect the other ones. How can I fix? Thanks

**Edit**: As suggested, I am going to show a screenshot of the final work. As you can see, the zero and the theta are "floating" with respect to the other items on the same line.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // Please include a screenshot in your question.

Comment: @MS-SPO, Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important change is to eliminate `inner sep` and use node's baseline as the baseline for the whole tikz picture. Additionally, `outer sep` is set so the arrow will keep a "safe distance" :_) from both nodes.

Also note [`tikzmark`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) does similar settings more automatic and you can find its use cases on this site.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\tikzset{
  my mark/.style={
    remember picture, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt, baseline=(#1.base)
  }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tikz[my mark=n3] \node (n3){1};  & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \tikz[my mark=n4] \node (n4){1}; & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick, ] (n3) to [out=45,in=135] node[above] {some text here} (n4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Also this is very nice, thank you! And thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

If you do it with `pstricks`, you won't have such a problem:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{pst-node}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \Rnode{n3}{1} & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    =
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \Rnode{n4}{1} & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \psset{linejoin=1, arrowinset=0.1}
    \nccurve[angleA=45, angleB=135,nodesep=1pt]{->}{n3}{n4}
    \naput[labelsep=2pt]{\text{some text here}}
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This work very very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=A]
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
=
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[name=B]
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,very thick] (A-1-2) to [out=45,in=135] node[above] {some text here} (B-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you also for your contribute!